# how to install OpenGL header files in Arch Linux

Tags: c++, opengl, header-files, archlinux

I am using Arch linux and trying to learn GLFW with C++ . I need to include OpenGL headers in my program . I have following cmake file in QtCreator:-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

 find_package(glfw3 3.2 REQUIRED)
 find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

 project(gt)
 add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

 target_include_directories(myapp ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
 target_link_libraries(gt ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
 target_link_libraries(gt ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY})
```

But QtCreator cant configure the file and I get folling error:-

```
/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137: error: Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR) /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE) /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:369 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS) CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)

:-1: error: Configuration failed.
```

I also had installed `base-devel` group while installing arch linux

here is output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` command:-

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 17.3.7
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 17.3.7
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: Install mesa and the packages related to your video board

Comment: @Amadeus I had installed mesa and packages related to my board

Comment: Can you print the results of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`?

Comment: @Amadeus Yes. See edit

Comment: So, last alternative is to see where is located `GL/gl.h`. Can you print the directory where it is?